# Shell can't open libs/init another shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script, that should import another shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

. libs/init
```

However it complains:

```
/sh/main.sh: 3: .: Can't open libs/init
```

the folder is structured as follows:

[image]

the content of the `init.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "<===========================================>"
echo "Check if all variables are set"
echo "<===========================================>"

[ -z "$DO_AC" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$K8S_CLUSTER" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$ARGO_SERVER" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$ARGO_USERNAME" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$ARGO_PW" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$IMAGE_URL" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$IMAGE_VERSION" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$CHARTS_URL" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$GITOPS_URL" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$APP_TYPE" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$APP" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$APP_URL" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$GIT_USER" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$GIT_AT" ] && exit 1
[ -z "$APP_TLS_SECRET" ] && exit 1
echo "All variables are set"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the full pathname of the lib directory. Pathnames are interpreted relative to the user's working directory, not the directory containing the script.

Comment: You don't have a `libs/init`. You have a `libs/init.sh`

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod u+r init.sh
```

That will make sure you've got read access to the file, which that error message suggested to me, might be your problem.  Permissions sometimes get changed for screwy reasons; as long as you're not randomly setting things suid root, however, it's not too much of a disaster.